# Undefined index with session

Tags: php, jquery, session, variables, undefined

I'm developing a chatbox script, and I have this page that checks if session is set, and if so, the certain elements of code should be hidden with jQuery. Here are my pages:

input.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">
    @import "stil.css";
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="postme.js"></script>
<?php
include_once('check.php');
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="chat">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <div id="input">
<form name="form"action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="tekst" id="msg" size="72" />
<input type="submit" name="dugme" value="posalji" id="dugme" />
</form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="black">
</div>
<div id="name">
<form name="yname">
<input type="text" name="tekst2" />
<input type="button" name="dugme2" value="Enter" onclick='send()' />    
</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

sesion.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['ime']=$_POST['ime'];
$sesion_n=$_SESSION['ime'];
echo $sesion_n;
?>
```

check.php:

```
<?php
include('sesion.php');
if (!isset($sesion_n)){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#black').hide();$('#name').hide();</script>";
}
?>
```

postme.js:

```
    function send(){
       $.post('sesion.php',{ime:yname.tekst2.value},function(val){
                if(val!=null) {
                    $('#black').fadeOut();
                    $('#name').hide();
                    alert(val);  
                }

            }

   )};
```

So the problem is that I get this error every time I run the page:
Notice: Undefined index: ime in C:\wamp\www\AJAX\sesion.php on line 3.
So can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['ime']))
{
    $_SESSION['ime']=$_POST['ime'];
    $sesion_n=$_SESSION['ime'];
    echo $sesion_n;
}
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="tekst2" /> change on 
<input type="text" name="tekst2" id="tekst2" /> and yname.tekst2.value change on $('#tekst2').value

Comment: Thanks, this fixes my notice, but the jQuery script doesn't hide the elements, so can you help me with that as well?

Comment: Do you have alert() after click "Enter" button?

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed it, and everything works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `$_POST['ime'];` is undefined and that means that you are not posting it i guess.

Are you sure that `yname.tekst2.value` is the correct way to access the value of the field?

If you have firebug you can check in the "console" tab what parametrs have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're loading `check.php` manually. That'd be a GET request, and will trash your stored value, as _POST won't be set on those pages. Probably won't be the cause of the undefined index problem, but something to consider.

Check that the session's ID value stays constant between requests. If it's different each time, you're getting a brand new blank session on each request.

Comment: I think that you might be onto something here, but can you explain me how can I check session IDs ?

Comment: use FireBug on firefox. It'd be in the cookies tab.

Comment: For some strange reason, this code isn't working in Firefox, and I tried Firebug and it's giving me yname is not defined error